# Exporting to csv while preserving digits for integers expressed in ".0" in R

Tags: r, csv, tidyverse, readr

I have the following dataframe:

```
myd <- data.frame(a = c(3.0, "2.0 (1.8, 2.2)"))
myd$a[1] <- format(round(as.numeric(myd$a[1]), 1), nsmall = 1)
```

My data looks like below:

```
myd
               a
1            3.0
2 2.0 (1.8, 2.2)
```

I want to export myd to csv (or excel). So I tried

```
write_csv(myd, "myd.csv")
```

However, row 1 and column 1 of the resultant csv file gives me a number 3 rather than 3.0. A screen shot of the csv is found as follows:

[image]

How can I create a .csv or .xlsx file that preserves the digits for the integers (output 3.0 rather than 3)? Hopefully this could be solved within the tidyverse ecosystem, but other solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything. The *write_csv* function does preserve the digits, but you don't see them when you open the file in Excel. See my screenshot. [image]